# Repeat function in python similar to R

Tags: python

Is there a repeat function in python similar to the rep function in R? If not, how to create one?

R has a powerful rep function as follows:

```
rep(x, times = 1, length.out = NA, each = 1)
```

- x:    a vector
- times: an integer-valued vector giving the (non-negative) number of times to repeat each element if of length length(x), or to repeat the whole vector if of length 1. Negative or NA values are an error. A double vector is accepted, other inputs being coerced to an integer or double vector.
- length.out: non-negative integer. The desired length of the output vector. Other inputs will be coerced to a double vector and the first element taken. Ignored if NA or invalid.
- each: non-negative integer. Each element of x is repeated each times. Other inputs will be coerced to an integer or double vector and the first element taken. Treated as 1 if NA or invalid.

Some examples are as follows:

```
R code
> letters
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v"
[23] "w" "x" "y" "z"
#Example 1
> rep(letters[1:3],times=c(1,2,4))
[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c"
#Example 2
> rep(letters[1:3],each=2,len=15)
 [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "b"
#repeat a:c each element 2 until length be 15
#Example 3
> rep(letters[1:3],each=3,times=2)
 [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
#repeat a:c each element 3  and repeat this 2 times
#Example 4
> rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE)],each=2)
 [1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "e" "e" "g" "g" "i" "i" "k" "k" "m" "m" "o" "o" "q" "q" "s" "s" "u" "u"
[23] "w" "w" "y" "y"
#Example 5
> rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],each=2)
 [1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "f" "f" "h" "h" "k" "k" "m" "m" "p" "p" "r" "r" "u" "u" "w" "w" "z" "z"
#Example 6
> rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],each=2,len=25)
[1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "f" "f" "h" "h" "k" "k" "m" "m" "p" "p" "r" "r" "u" "u" "w" "w" "z" "z"
[23] "a" "a" "c"
```

As we saw above, the rep function can produce complex sequences. So, is there a function that does the same as R's rep? If not, at least how to create a similar one? The function should handle all of the above examples to check its flexibility!

Comment: Please always include the [tag:numpy] tag when asking questions about NumPy, as described in the [tag:python] tag wiki. NumPy adds its own data structures, functions to operate on them, and programming idioms that are quite different from vanilla Python.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are asking? Are you asking for a function that does the same as R's ``rep``? Are you asking how to do each operation? Are you asking specifically about numpy, or generally about the native equivalent of arrays i.e. lists?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, I think the question is clear! Could you create a function in python with similar to R rep function. Your function should handle all of the examples to check its flexibility! Look at the answer just added!

Comment: @Masoud So the reply to my queries is "yes", "no", "just lists" then? Of course *you* know what *you* intended to ask and can this write an answer to your intended question, but that does not mean that someone else understands the question the same way. Please [edit] the question to spell out the requirements instead of expecting people to pick them out of an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Its not quite clear what you want to achieve.
You can use `slicing` to get an equivalent output in numpy like Example 4, or you can use `indexing` with a mask to get your desired results (Example 5). There is not an exact equivalent function in python.

```
# Example 4
import numpy as np
import string
letters =string.ascii_lowercase
letters =list(letters)

print(np.repeat(letters[::2],2))

['a' 'a' 'c' 'c' 'e' 'e' 'g' 'g' 'i' 'i' 'k' 'k' 'm' 'm' 'o' 'o' 'q' 'q'
 's' 's' 'u' 'u' 'w' 'w' 'y' 'y']

# Example 5
import numpy as np
import string
letters =string.ascii_lowercase  
letters = np.array(list(letters))

indicies = [(0,2,5,7,10,12,15,17,20,22,25)]

print(np.repeat(letters[indicies],2))

['a' 'a' 'c' 'c' 'f' 'f' 'h' 'h' 'k' 'k' 'm' 'm' 'p' 'p' 'r' 'r' 'u' 'u'
 'w' 'w' 'z' 'z']
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found an easy solution. It is not exactly the same as  the rep function in R. But it is good enough to handle the examples. Here is a rep function in Python:

```
import numpy as np
def rep(lst, each=[1] ,times=1  , length_out= -1):
    if len(each) < len(lst):
        mul_each = len(lst) // len(each) + 1
        each = each * mul_each
        each=each[:len(lst)]
    ls=np.repeat(lst,repeats=each)
    ls=ls.tolist() * times
    if length_out != -1:
        if length_out < len(ls):
            ls[:length_out]
        else:
            mul = length_out // len(ls) + 1
            ls = ls * mul
        return ls[:length_out]
    return ls
```

It is very simple and powerfull. Now look at how it can handle all examples in the question:

```
import string
letters =string.ascii_lowercase
letters =list(letters)
```

**1.**

```
# R code
#> rep(letters[1:3],times=c(1,2,4))
#[1] "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "c"
# Python code 
rep(letters[0:3], each=[1,2,4] ,times=1  , length_out= -1)
# output ['a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

**2.**

```
#R code
#> rep(letters[1:3],each=2,len=15)
# [1] "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "b" "b" "c" "c" "a" "a" "b"
# Python code
rep(letters[0:3], each=[2] ,times=1  , length_out= 15)
# output ['a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'b']
```

**3.**

```
#R code
#> rep(letters[1:3],each=3,times=2)
# [1] "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "c" "c" "c"
# Python code
rep(letters[0:3], each=[3] ,times=2)
# output ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'c']
```

**4.**

```
# R code
#> rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE)],each=2)
# [1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "e" "e" "g" "g" "i" "i" "k" "k" "m" "m" "o" "o" "q" "q" "s" "s" "u" "u" "w" "w" "y" "y"
# python code    
rep(letters[::2], each=[2])
#output ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'e', 'e', 'g', 'g', 'i', 'i', 'k', 'k', 'm', 'm', 'o', 'o', 'q', 'q', 's', 's', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'y', 'y']
```

**5.**

```
# R code
#rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],each=2)
# [1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "f" "f" "h" "h" "k" "k" "m" "m" "p" "p" "r" "r" "u" "u" "w" "w" "z" "z"
#Python code
TF=[True,False,True,False,False]
TF_all=rep(TF,length_out=len(letters))
index_letters=[letters[i] for i, x in enumerate(TF_all) if x]
rep(index_letters, each=[2])
# output ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'm', 'm', 'p', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'z', 'z']
```

**6.**

```
# R code
#> rep(letters[c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)],each=2,len=25)
#[1] "a" "a" "c" "c" "f" "f" "h" "h" "k" "k" "m" "m" "p" "p" "r" "r" "u" "u" "w" "w" "z" "z" "a" "a" "c"
# Python code
TF=[True,False,True,False,False]
TF_all=rep(TF,length_out=len(letters))
index_letters=[letters[i] for i, x in enumerate(TF_all) if x]
rep(index_letters, each=[2], length_out= 25)
# output ['a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'f', 'f', 'h', 'h', 'k', 'k', 'm', 'm', 'p', 'p', 'r', 'r', 'u', 'u', 'w', 'w', 'z', 'z', 'a', 'a', 'c']
```

Comment: A good way to select a subset: import itertools
x = [1,0,1]
y = range(1,35)
r = int(len(y) / len(x) +1)
z = itertools.compress(y,x*r)

Comment: Another way: index = itertools.cycle(x)
z = itertools.compress(y,index)
list(z)[:5]